Did Prophet Muhammad (SAW) ever marry any non-muslims?
Did Prophet Muhammad (SAW) ever marry any non-muslims? If yes who were they?

No.
He did marry a number of women who were converts to Islam and had been non-Muslims (polytheists or Jews) at some point before the marriage but I don't think that this is what you are asking about.
There is disagreement on whether he had any concubine who was not a Muslim as there are claims that he had relations with his concubine Rayhaanah while she was still a Jew, but there are conflicting reports about her.
He did not however 'marry' any woman while she was still a non-Muslim at the time of marriage. A number of scholars have stated that it was a specialty of the Prophet ﵆ that he was forbidden to marry a Kitabi woman, and he only allowed to marry Muslims - while an ordinary Muslim man is permitted to marry a Kitabi woman. This obviously means that he did not marry any non-Muslims.

قال ابن عباس رضى الله عنهما نهي رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم عن أصناف النساء إلا ما كان من المؤمنات المهاجرات
Narrated Ibn Abbas: All types of women were prohibited for the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) except for the believing women among those who emigrated.
— Jami at-Tirmidhi

Ref: Khasaa’is al-Kubra, Asna al-Mataalib, Kashshaaf al-Qinaa’, Mawaahib al-Jaleel

Only two wives of Prophet Muhammad are known to have come from non-Muslim backgrounds before converting to Islam:

Maria al-Qibtiyya (a Coptic Christian)


Maria al-Qibtiyya (may Allah be pleased with her) is said to have married the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) and certainly everyone gave her the same title of respect as the Prophet's wives, 'Umm al Muminin' 'Mother of the Believers'. Maria was born in upper Egypt of a Coptic father and Greek mother and moved to the court of the Muqawqis when she was still very young. She arrived in Medina to join the Prophet's household just after the Prophet returned from the treaty with Quraish which was contracted at al-Hudaybiyya. Maria gave birth to a healthy son in 9 AH, the same year that his daughter Zaynab died, and the Prophet named his new son Ibrahim,


Safiyya bint Huyayy (of Jewish heritage).


Safiyya bint Huyayy, (may Allah be pleased with her) married the Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) in 7 AH, when the Prophet was sixty years old and she was seventeen years old. As in the case of juwayriyya bint Harith, this marriage occurred after one of the Muslims' decisive battles, in this case, the battle of Khaybar. After the battle of Khaybar in which the Muslims defeated the Jews, two women were brought before the Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) by Bilal,
…
The Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) invited Safiyya to embrace Islam, which she did, and having given her, her freedom, he then married her.


[Reference: Al-Sira al-Nabawiyya by Ibn Kathir]
